# Issues with csrf token field being empty

Tags: php, laravel, csrf

I'm pretty brand new to php/laravel (bear with me!) and am having some issues with csrf tokens for one of my forms. I've included the code to the entire view, but the form I'm having issues with is the #editActionDueDate modal. When hitting edit on the modal form, it returns a 419 error. I've tried passing the csrf token with every way I can think of, but I can't get the token through. It just passes an empty value for that token parameter.

Every other form on my site is working just fine, so I'm a little confused.

The only difference I can think of with this form is that it has a modified script to pass the information of the current due_date to the form itself - everything else is identical and from what I've asked some of our developers, this should not affect it.

Also, if I exclude this uri from the csrf verification middleware, it works fine.

Any ideas of what could be causing the token field to be empty?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>View Action Details</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>

    <script>
    // Open "edit due date" modal and pass due_date info
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#editActionDueDate').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {

        var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
        var due_date = button.data('due_date') // Extract info from data-* attributes
        var modal = $(this)

        modal.find('.modal-body input').val(due_date)
        });
    })
    </script>
    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    @include('nav')
    <div>

        @foreach($action as $act)
        <a href="{{ route('patient', $act->patient_id) }}">Return to patient profile</a>
        @endforeach

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#insertActionNote">
            + Action Note
        </button>

    </div>
    <div>
        <h3>Action View</h3>
        @foreach($action as $act)
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>Action ID</th>
                <th>Patient</th>
                <th>Created Date</th>
                <th>Last Modified Date</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $act->action_id}}</td>
                <td>{{ $act->first_name.' '.$act->last_name}}</td>
                <td>{{ $act->created_at}}</td>
                <td>{{ $act->updated_at}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Action</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Due Date</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $act->option_text}}</td>
                <td>{{ $act->action_status_name}}</td>
                <td>{{ $act->due_date}}</td>
                <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editActionDueDate" data-due_date="{{ $act->due_date }}">Edit</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        @endforeach
    </div>
    <div>
    <h3>Notes</h3>
    <table class="table">
        @foreach($notes as $note)
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Date: {{$note->created_at}}</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Submitted By: {{$note->user_name}}</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{{$note->note_text}}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </table>

    {{ $notes->links() }}

    </div>

    <!-- This modal form works fine -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="insertActionNote" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="insertActionNoteLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="insertActionNoteLabel">Add New Note</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('addActionNote') }}">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}

                    <input id="user_id" type="hidden" name="user_id" value="{{ Auth::user()->user_id }}" >
                    <input id="action_id" type="hidden" name="action_id" value="{{ $act->action_id }}" >

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="note_text" class="col-md-2 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Note') }}</label>

                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <textarea id="note_text" name="note_text" type="text" class="form-control @error('note_text') is-invalid @enderror" rows="4" value="{{ old('note_text') }}" required autofocus></textarea>

                            @error('note_text')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                            {{ __('Add Note') }}
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- This modal form is passing an empty token-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="editActionDueDate" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editActionDueDateLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="editActionDueDateLabel">Edit Due Date</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('editActionDueDate') }}">
                        {!! csrf_field() !!}

                    <input id="action_id" type="hidden" name="action_id" value="{{ $act->action_id }}" >

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="note_text" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Due Date') }}</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="due_date" type="text" class="form-control @error('due_date') is-invalid @enderror" name="due_date" value="{{ old('due_date') }}" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" autofocus>

                            @error('due_date')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                            {{ __('Edit Due Date') }}
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

use App\Http\Controllers\PatientController;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::post('/addAction', 'ActionController@store')->name('addAction');
Route::post('/addPatientNote', 'PatientNoteController@store')->name('addPatientNote');
Route::post('/addActionNote', 'ActionNoteController@store')->name('addActionNote');
Route::post('/editActionDueDate/{action_id}', 'ActionController@editActionDueDate')->name('editActionDueDate');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/registerPatient', 'PatientController@showPatientRegistrationForm')->name('registerPatient');
Route::post('/registerPatient', 'PatientController@store');
Route::post('/editPatient', 'PatientController@update')->name('editPatient');
Route::get('/patient/{patient_id}', 'PatientController@show')->name('patient');

Route::get('/viewAction/{action_id}', 'ActionController@show')->name('viewAction');

Route::get('dashboard', 'ActionController@index')->name('actions.index');
Route::get('getActions', 'ActionController@getActionsTable')->name('get.actions');



Route::resource('users', 'UserController');



Route::get('/addQuestion', 'QuestionController@showNewQuestions')->name('addQuestion');
Route::post('/addQuestion', 'QuestionController@storeNewQuestionAndOptions');
```

Comment: The one that works fine is using `{{ csrf_field() }}` the broken one is using 
`{!! csrf_field() !!}` Have you tried using `{{ csrf_field() }}` for both?

Comment: Sorry, that was just a left over of trying things. I've tried with {{ csrf_fiedl() }} and {!! csrf_field() !!} and it's always that one form that isn't working.
I also tried to pass {{ csrf_token() }} as a hidden input, but that also did not work - which may be by design.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with your route. Are you using the "web" middleware? It not try moving your route inside.

The laravel documentation on this subject is pretty good:
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/middleware

Comment: The route appears to be working fine. I'm using web for my routes.

If I exclude this URI from the VerifyCsrfToken middleware, then the request hits my controller and I can dd($request) and see a XSRF-TOKEN under cookies>parameters

But as soon as I remove that exclusion, then it throws a 419 page expired error.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Laravel are you using? If I've read it correctly, and the form that's failing you is the update, it may be because you're missing the method. In the update form you must put the CSRF token and specify that you will use the `put` method to update.

You must also pass the id of the element you want to update to the action of the form.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('editActionDueDate', $act->action_id ) }}">

    @csrf

    @method('PUT')

    // inputs and other stuff

</form>
```

See more:

[csfr protection](https://laravel.com/docs/master/csrf)

[Method field](https://laravel.com/docs/master/blade#method-field)

Comment: Ah, PUT method. Good point. I've added the method, but it's still throwing 419 error.

But you've given me something that I've completely missed to look at, and I appreciate it. I'm going to first remove all unnecessary code form my form and try a simple/single-field update and see if that goes through. 

Also, I'm on laravel 6.14

Comment: Can we see your routes in web.php? and your controller.

Comment: I edited the original post and added web.php - thank you

Comment: In your table, the id field is called `action_id`? If you exclude this URI from the VerifyCsrfToken middleware, the updated work properly?

Comment: Correct, action_id is the field/primary key. If I exclude the URI in the csrf controller, then it was not updating correctly because, originally, it was not passing an action_id, or rather, it was empty because the form didn't have that data. If I hardcode an action_id in the controller, then it works fine and updates the due_date (I don't know if this explanation makes sense).

Comment: If I pass the action_id in the action as action="{{ route('editActionDueDate', $act->action_id ) }}" it also throws 419 error. I will spend some time and build the form from scratch and include as little as possible to make an edit work - thank you for your help. I would "up arrow" your answer, but I don't seem to have enough rep.

Comment: As soon as I comment my edited javascript to pass the due_date (at the top of the code) it works like a charm. I'm having a hard time getting this to work while passing the due_date info to the modal :/

Comment: Nice! Check if you have in your .env file `APP_DEBUG=true` to see php errors instead of an error code page..